# Object reshaping with openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I am working on an application that display objects (importing STL files) and to transform them into 2D slices.
example:
[image: Work illustration]

Currently, the vertices are stored in a VBO, vertex shader doesn't transform anything, then I test the intersection of triangles and slice heights, and I emit new triangles to have a discretized shape. Finish with light calculation in fragment shader.

I have 3 problems:

- I only have the vertical part, the object is not closed (seen from the top, you only see thin lines). It is hard to compute that with 1 triangle aware shader.
- I have hardware limitation, the number of primitives a GS can emit is not infinite, so if I want a very small slice height, I can't emit enough vertices.
- IT IS VERY SLOW!!!!

**I know I am doing some kind of tesselation, so do you think moving this work in tesselation shaders would improve performance?
More generaly, how would you do that?**

(I want to add that I work on 2 million+ objects, so discretize them and stock the vertices via transform feedback for example may be hard due to the amount of vertices graphic card can handle.)

I work on Windows 7/10, C++11 compiled by msvc2012, with Qt 5.2.1 and openGL (not sure about the version, but it is at least 3.2 and maybe 4+. I can still upgrade if needed).

Comment: Indeed you should move that work in tesselation shaders. If not already done, read the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tessellation) and let us know if you need more information